# Do chargers consume power when plugged but not used?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-management

Many people leave their chargers for mobile phones, laptops, devices of any kind plugged into the power socket but without the device they are supposed to charge, connected at the other end.

When doing so, do these chargers actually consumer electricity? If yes, is it a lot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the type of power transformer in there. The latest generation of ["Switched-mode power supplies"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply) is quite efficient and does not draw that much when not in use, compared to traditional ones.

And there are two reasons for making it very hard to actually measure the power it draws with a regular electricity meter. First, it's just a very small amount they consume, and, second, it uses pulse-width modulation techniques with adjustable duty-cycle on the AC side

While newer generation chargers/AC-DC adapters will consume just tiny bits, it is very advisable to just remove them from any power source for power saving reasons. I use power strips with a switch to cut the power completely with ease when I'm gone or asleep.

Answer (score 1):

YES these things do consume power if they are plugged into the wall.

Comment: Yep, it's been called parasitic load or vampire loading dependent on who you talk to. Same thing goes for a lot of electrical equipment. In the old days when electronics glowed, the off switch actually turned things off. In this day of impatience and instant on, there can be quite a bit of power burned to heat the atmosphere for very little return, so watch for EnergyStar ratings on parasitic power requirements.